# Avoiding repetitive if statements without using a switch?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm making tic tac toe for a school project and have created a method called checkWin(char[][] board) that checks each combination of answers to see if there is a winning board. This runs after each turn and works perfectly, but totals 16 if statements, one for each potential win combination for each side. Because I'm checking combinations of different array elements, I can't use a switch, but is there any other way to avoid the large number of repetitive switch statements?

Comment: Show the code you have written so far regarding what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use some kind of an array of objects.

Here is a simplistic version using `int[2]` for each point but you should really use a `Point` class with an `x` and `y` coordinate. This should demonstrate how easy it can be if you use data structures.

```
// The point coordinates of each point in each possible winning line.
static final int[][][] LINES = {
        {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}},
        {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}},
        {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}},
        {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}},
        {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}},
        {{0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}},
        {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}},
        {{2, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}},
};
// The players.
static final int PLAYER1 = 1;
static final int PLAYER2 = -1;

private int checkWin(int[][] board) {
    // Check each line.
    for (int[][] line : LINES) {
        // Add up the total value of each line.
        int total = 0;
        for (int[] point : line) {
            // Use the point to specify which square on the board to check.
            total += board[point[0]][point[1]];
        }
        // If the total adds up to 3 or -3 then someone has won on this line.
        if (total == line.length * PLAYER1) {
            return PLAYER1;
        }
        if (total == line.length * PLAYER2) {
            return PLAYER2;
        }
    }
    // Nobody won.
    return 0;
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = new int[3][];
    for ( int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        board[i] = new int[3];
    }
    // Set up a win..
    board[0][0] = PLAYER1;
    board[1][1] = PLAYER1;
    board[2][2] = PLAYER1;
    int winner = checkWin(board);
    System.out.println(winner);
}
```